# handeling two client on one server in android

Tags: android, sockets

i developed a chat application client/server now i wanat create application that two client connect to server and Together chat
this is my code

// server code

`public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {`
`private TextView textview;`
    `private Button btnchat;`
    `private EditText editText;`
    `Handler handler=new Handler();`
    `private Socket socket;`
    `BufferedReader inputstream;`
    `DataOutputStream outputStream;`

```
`@Override`
`protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {`
    `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`
    `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`
    `textview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);`
    `btnchat=(Button)findViewById(R.id.chatbutton);`
    `editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);`


    `Thread t=new Thread(new Runnable() {`
        `@Override`
        `public void run() {`

            `try {`

                `ServerSocket serverSocket=new ServerSocket(9000);`
                `log("watinng for client");`
                `socket =serverSocket.accept();`
                `log("a new client connected");`
                `outputStream=new` `DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());`
                `inputstream=new BufferedReader(new` `InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));`
                `log("buffer initialized");`
                `while (true){`
                    `String getfromserver=inputstream.readLine();`

                    `log(getfromserver);`
                `}`
                `//outputStream.write("hello from server\n".getBytes());`
            `} catch (IOException e) {`
                `e.printStackTrace();`
            `}`
        `}`
    `});`
            `btnchat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {`
        `@Override`
        `public void onClick(View v) {`

            `try {`
                `outputStream.write((editText.getText()+"\n").getBytes());`
                `editText.setText("");`
            `} catch (IOException e) {`
                `e.printStackTrace();`
            `}`


        `}`
    `});`
    `t.start();`
`}`
`public void log(final String message){`
    `handler.post(new Runnable(){`
        `@Override`
    `public void run(){`
            `textview.setText(textview.getText()+"\n"+ message);`
        `}`


    `});`
`}`

`@Override`
`public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {`
    `if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){`
        `System.exit(0);`
        `return true;`
    `}`
    `return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);`
`}`
```

`}`

//my client code

`public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {`

```
`private Handler handler=new Handler();`
`private TextView textview;`
`private Button btnchat;`
`private EditText editText;`
`private Socket socket;`
`BufferedReader inputstream;`
`DataOutputStream outputStream;`

`@Override`
`protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {`
    `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`
    `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`
    `textview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);`
    `btnchat=(Button)findViewById(R.id.chatbutton);`
    `editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);`
    `//server ip: 192.168.43.54`

    `Thread thread=new Thread(new Runnable() {`
        `@Override`
        `public void run() {`

            `try {`
                `log("connecting");`
                `socket=new Socket("192.168.43.54",9000);`

                `log("connected");`
                `outputStream=new` `DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());`
                `inputstream =new BufferedReader(new` `InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));`
           `log("buffer initialized");`
               `// outputStream.write("hello from client\n".getBytes());`
                `while (true){`
                    `String getfromserver=inputstream.readLine();`
                    `log(getfromserver);`
                `}`

            `} catch (IOException e) {`
                `e.printStackTrace();`
            `}`

        `}`
    `});`
    `btnchat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {`
        `@Override`
        `public void onClick(View v) {`
            `try {`
               `if(outputStream==null){`
                   `return;`
               `}`
                `outputStream.write((editText.getText()+"\n").getBytes());`
                `editText.setText("");`
            `} catch (IOException e) {`
                `e.printStackTrace();`
            `}`

        `}`
    `});`
    `thread.start();`


`}`
`public void log(final String message){`
    `handler.post(new Runnable() {`
        `@Override`
        `public void run() {`

            `textview.setText(textview.getText()+"\n"+message);`

        `}`
    `});`
`}`

`@Override`
`public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {`
    `if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){`
        `System.exit(0);`
        `return true;`
    `}`
    `return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);`
`}`
```

`}`

please help me ,i need help,
//Excuseme for english

Comment: `i developed a chat application client/server `. Ok. So you have an Android client app and an Android server app. Ok.  `now i wanat create application that two client connect to server`. That i do not understand. You do not need yet an app. You only have to start your client app on two Android devices so the users can chat. Please explain better the problem you have. `handeling two client on one server in android`. Yes that will be your problem.

Comment: So at the moment two users can only chat if one has the server and the other has the client? Does that work? And now you want a third user? Or two users both with a client?

Comment: now i have 2 app one for server one for client,i want create Two other app one for server and one for two client

Comment: i want client chating togetheaar ,they send their message to server and server send to other client

Comment: Answer all my questions before we continue.

Comment: i want 2 user both client and that they have one server ,they connect to one server

Comment: excuse me i cant speak english well,
do you understand my intended purpose?

Comment: Yes. But first i wanna know what your client and server app are able to now.

Comment: when i install my client app on two device juast one device can chat with server and other device doesnt work,i want two client chat together and they connect to one server for send or recive messages

Comment: my client and server now just can chating with together

Comment: Well tell the problem(s) you have. What is exactly your problem? For adapting the server to handle more clients you have to change a lot. So where do you start? What is the problem that you want to solve first?

Comment: 'private Socket socket;'. You have ticks '  ' around every line. Please post your code in a normal way. Without those ticks. In case some one wants to try your code you make copy/past impossible. Remove those ticks.

Comment: I 'm confused I do not know how to change the apps ,i dont know how two client can connecting together on the server

Comment: Well i think two clients can already connect now. You do not have to do anyting for that. And both can send messages to the server alreay you said. But indeed the server will not send a message received from one client to the other now.

Comment: Please first check if two clients can connect.

Comment: client can connect to server but can not seend or recive message
excuse me i dont know how to edit my post

Comment: There is an 'edit' link for that.

Comment: i know but when i remove "`" i cant send post i get eror

Comment: Very strange. Look at other posts on this site. Nobody has those ticks. So what is the error? You should not remover those ticks. You should just again copy/past code from IDE to your browser. Who is adding those ticks?

Comment: You posted the same code for client and server. Please edit.

Comment: oh i copied client code for server code,edited

Comment: You still have those ticks. Please remove them first. Post code in a normal way.

Comment: i can not edit this post when i edit post i get eror "

    Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:

    Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.
"

Comment: when you paste this code .refactor rename "`" with sapce

Comment: Sorry. I will wait until you learned to post code in a normal way.

Comment: i cant
help me please